# C formula can't get correct value

Tags: c, printf, formula, scanf

I need help with a formula for the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int MAGNUM, AK47, Knife, Axe, total;
    char choice, choice2, confirm;

    MAGNUM = 75;
    AK47 = 150;
    Knife = 40;
    Axe = 20;

    printf("Welcome to weapon store.\n");
    printf("Over here, we sell cheap weaponry you may be interested in.\n");
    printf("Currently, this is what we have for sale:\n\n\n");
    printf("(A) .44 MAGNUM\n");
    printf("(B) AK-47\n");
    printf("(C) Laredo Bowie knife\n");
    printf("(D) Tomahawk axe\n\n\n");
    printf("Pick one to buy, just type the letter in caps of the item and press enter.\n");
    printf("ITEM SELECTED:");
    scanf("%c", &choice);   //First input//

    if (choice == 'A')
    {
        printf("That will be $%d.\n", MAGNUM);
    }

    if (choice == 'B')
    {
        printf("That will be $%d.\n", AK47);
    }
    if (choice == 'C')
    {
        printf("That will be $%d.\n", Knife);
    }
    if (choice == 'D')
    {
        printf("That will be $%d.\n", Axe);
    }
    printf("Do you want to buy anything else?<Y//N>\n");    //Second input//
    scanf(" %c", &choice2);

    if (choice2 == 'Y')
    {
        printf("What else do you want to buy:");    //Third input//
        scanf(" %c", &confirm);
        if (confirm == 'A')
        {
            printf("That will be $%d.\n ", MAGNUM);
        }
        else if (confirm == 'B')
        {
            printf("That will be $%d.\n", AK47);
        }
        else if (confirm == 'C')
        {
            printf("That will be $%d.\n", Knife);
        }
        else if (confirm == 'D')
        {
            printf("That will be $%d.\n", Axe);
        }

        total = choice + confirm;   //Need help with formula here. total equals first input + third input//

        printf("Total cost is $%d. Thank you.\n", total);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Thank you for shopping with us.\n");    
    }
}
```

When debugged, it wont show the correct values of inputs 1 and 3, when added together.

For example, if I select D and then D again for inputs 1 and 3 respectively, I should get $40 for total, but instead I get a different value of $136.

It might be my lack of C knowledge at the moment, as I had only started 2 days ago. This code is just a testing ground for my knowledge of basics such as if else statements etc, so I apologize if the content in the code may be offensive to anyone.

Comment: Though I don't like weapons, that's not the offending part of your question. See how to  provide a  [MCVE] please.

Comment: You're not adding the prices, you're adding the letters that the user typed. `'D'` is character code `68`, so `choice + confirm = 136`.

Comment: Add another variable like `totalPrice` or something. then `+=` the price on each if.

Comment: "lack of c++ knowledge". This is C, not C++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ After I removed the `**` highlighting, it compiled. Why isn't it a MCVE?

Comment: @Barmar There's certainly more potential to shorten the given code to reproduce the problem. Let's say demonstrate with just two choices or so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wow, that's really picky. So he should have just 2 choices instead of 4? Not print the menu? This is so much better of a MCVE than 90% of questions we get here.

Comment: @Barmar I'm also missing debugging efforts explained, there's just a statement the OP debugged the code, but without giving more evidence what actually was observed. Well, let's face it: Would you really judge that question being helpful for future research? Start with the title.

Comment: That's a completely different complaint than it not being a MCVE. The guy just started programming 2 days ago, and guess what, he has no idea what he's doing.

Comment: @Barmar [MCVE] actually asks for showing the debugging efforts made (at least the corresponding close reason does).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You've been here long enough to know that we hardly ever get that, it's a requirement in name only. This question is so much better than most of the "It doesn't work" questions. He ran the program. He gave the inputs D and D. Instead of getting the expected result 40, he got 136.

Comment: Everything you need to know to understand the problem he had and how to fix it is in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the character values not the prices.

68 is 'D' interpreted as an integer. 68+68=136.

I would add the prices in your if statements, e.g.

```
if (choice == 'D')
{
printf("That will be $%d.\n", Axe);
total=total+Axe;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `total`.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

It was my mistake in putting C++ as title. Did not realise that oddly. Also didn't know about character values before.

Initialising a grandtotal = total1 + total2, where total1 represents the value of chosen outcome of input 1, and total2 represents value of chosen outcome for input 3, solved the problem.